# Making a cell Mandatory based on conditional formatting of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am looking to achieve the following:

`Column C` has been conditionally formatted based on data entry: if the entered data is out of range, cell background will turn red.

I want to force a data entry at the bottom of the sheet via a mandatory inputbox whenever data has been entered and the cell is conditionally formatted red due to out of range data.

Below is the code I have tried:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If target.rows.count > 1 or target.columns.count > 1 Then
   Exit Sub
End If

Dim com As String
Dim comm1 As String

Set isect=Application.Intersect(target,Range("C1:C100"))
If isect Is Nothing Then

Else

If target.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0) Then
   com = "Enter comment at bottom of sheet"

   Do While comm1 = ""
      comm1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:=com, Type:=2)
      On Error GoTo myloop
      If comm1 = False Then
          comm1 = ""
      End If

myloop:
   On Error GoTo -1
   Loop
   Range("B101").Value = comm1

Else
   Range("B101").Value = ""
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: see [Range.DisplayFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat)

Comment: I changed it to target.Interior.ColorIndex but it still didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is because it isn't returning any error messages or anything like that. Just not working.

Comment: `target.displayformat.interior.color`

Comment: It appears to be working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now i have another question. How would you modify the code so that if B101 already contains text the the inputbox would enter into the cell below it (B102), and if that contains text then it would move to B103 and so on.

Comment: That is a new question, and should be posted as such.